# How to know which LAPACK's function is used by Scipy's eig function?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, scipy, lapack

As far as I understood, `scipy.linalg.eig` use wrappers from `scipy.lapack` to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. In order to do that `eig` test the matrix to select the good LAPACK function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

When the matrix is singular and the algorithm does not converge Python raises an error and displays the name of the LAPACK function used. I would like to know which algorithm `eig` uses when I compute the eigenvalues of the matrix. Is there any `scipy` function or `eig` option that I am not aware of displaying the LAPACK function used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to display the used LAPACK function names natively during runtime using the interfaces provided by `scipy.linalg`.

Depending on your goals you can:

- read the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/linalg/decomp.py#L118-L267) and deduce the logic from there. Unfortunately, this is not a runtime-use scenario, but a human analysis.
- fork your own version of `scipy`, add custom outputs (to the calls you are interested in monitoring) and use it instead of the shipped one. Since `scipy` is open-source, with some manual work you can get the desired behavior. [Building scipy from sources reference](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/) should be useful in this case.

---

Regarding [`scipy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig): this function is for the general matrices. If you happen to have a symmetric/Hermittian, banded or tridiagonal matrix, you should call [`scipy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html#scipy.linalg.eigh), [`scipy.linalg_eig_banded`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig_banded.html#scipy.linalg.eig_banded), or [`scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal.html#scipy.linalg.eigh_tridiagonal), respectively.

You can see that `scipy.linalg.eig` [does not do any chosing](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/decomp.py#L228) of LAPACK functions to use:

> ```
> geev, geev_lwork = get_lapack_funcs(('geev', 'geev_lwork'), (a1,))
> ```

So, `scipy.linalg.eig` will call the [?geev](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/469230). I don't think it is physically capable (as of the current implementation) of calling anything else.

On the contrary, [`scipy.linalg.eigh`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/decomp.py#L270) has more options and flexibility, and actually different LAPACK functions can be called from `scipy`.

---

Note, that currently, you are probably seeing the output of [scipy.linalg.LinAlgError](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.LinAlgError.html). This exception is raised in the linear algebra functions wrappers and probably uses the `info` output from the called LAPACK function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very useful. I mainly work on general matrices so I'm stuck with `scipy.linalg.eig`.  Looks like  `?geev` is testing the matrix itself before selecting `dgeev` or other LAPACK function to run the calculation.
I will try to modify the sources to get what I want later in the year.